# Better way to communicate between Java Servlet and a normal Java Application

Tags: java, servlets, ipc

So, I guess it would be best to start with the use-case of the Application I am planning.

I am planning to create an Audioplayer onto which everyone in the local network can upload music via a Webpage and vote for specific songs. The song with the most votes shall then be played and visualized. It should also be possible to play and pause the current song via the web interface.

So my Solution would be to write two applications; The first one is a player, which should play the songs and visualize them as well as get the next song from a Database. The other part would be a servlet, which handles the File-Upload to the player and the Processing of ID3 Tags and eventual insertion into the Database.

So far, so good. Now I need a way to quickly communicate the Play/Pause Events as well as possible events to change the visualization. I have come up with multiple solutions:

1. Use Java Message Services with Apache ActiveMQ to exchange the
   Events between the Frontend and the Visualization. (Should be
   possible with MessageListeners, so the response would be quick, but
   requires Apache ActiveMQ as an additional Technology)
2. Write such commands into a Table and have the player check with a
   thread every half second or so (Downside: might seem laggy as the
   interval is low and also creates load on the server PC / Raspberry
   Pi)
3. Sockets

Is there a better way to solve this communication, because all of these solutions do not seem ideal?

Answer (score 0):

I guess best way would be to use Threads implemented with wait and notify mechanism where song player would wait for response from the servlet and as soon as servlet receives the response it would notify the player to play the song.

This thread would act as a bridge between servlet and song player.

Comment: How would that work? Aren't threads only accessible from the program that launched them?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this sample program to demonstrate the flow. Here you can assume ThreadA as song player and ThreadB as voting application and then proceed . Write the business logic before sending notify call.

```
package com.WaitNotify;

    public class ThreadA {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized (b) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete");
                b.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("total is " + b.getTotal());

        }

    }

}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    private int total = 0;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                this.total += 1;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Operationcompleted-- Going to notify");
            notify();
        }
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your effort. The thing is, that the Java Servlet is run by Tomcat when requested. It will reside in a different Package. As far as I understand threads, this inter-thread communication only works if they are in the same program. I guess that does not work if there are two seperate programs like in my case.